# UDP send data from one device to another

Tags: java, android, networking, udp

I'm trying to send over a small packet from one device to another,
My device ip is 192.168.1.59 which is the host,
Here is my server code

```
public class gameServer extends Thread{

/**
 * Sets up a server for Android applciation
 */
private static final String TAG = "GameServer";
private DatagramSocket socket;
private int port = 50000;
private InetAddress local = null;

public gameServer(  ) throws IOException
{
    socket = new DatagramSocket( port );
    Log.d(TAG, "Server was setup");
}

private String getLocalIPAddress()
{
    try
    {
        for (Enumeration<NetworkInterface> nis = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces(); nis.hasMoreElements();)
        {
            NetworkInterface ni = nis.nextElement();
            Log.v(TAG, "NetworkInterface = " + ni.getDisplayName());
            for (Enumeration<InetAddress> ips = ni.getInetAddresses(); ips.hasMoreElements();)
            {
                InetAddress ip = ips.nextElement();
                String s = ip.getHostAddress();
                Log.v(TAG, "InetAddress = " + s);
                if (!ip.isLoopbackAddress())
                {
                            if(InetAddressUtils.isIPv4Address(s)) return s;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException e)
    {
            Log.e(TAG,"getLocalIPAddress()", e);
    }
    return null;
}

public void passClient( gameObject clientTemp )
{

}

@Override
public void run()
{
    Log.d(TAG, "Ip address used:" + getLocalIPAddress() );
    while( true )
    {
        //Send some data
        try 
        {
            local = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        String msg = "hello there";
        int msgLength = msg.length();
        byte[] message = msg.getBytes();
        DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket( message, msgLength, local, port );
        try 
        {
            socket.send( p );
        } 
        catch (IOException e2) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error with sending");
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
}
```

Here is my client

```
public class gameClient extends Thread {

private static final String TAG = "gameClient";
private gameServer server;
private boolean rdyForPlay = false;
private ArrayList<gameObject> assets = new ArrayList();
private int ID = 0;
private maths cal = new maths();

public gameClient( boolean serverTag )
{
    if( serverTag == true)
    {
        try 
        {
            server = new gameServer();
            server.run();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Could not start server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //DELETE!!!
        //ONLY FOR TESTING
        DatagramSocket socket = null;;
        try 
        {
            socket = new DatagramSocket( 50000 );
        } 
        catch (SocketException e1) 
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
        try 
        {
            socket.receive( packet );
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String data = new String( buf, 0, packet.getLength() );

        Log.d(TAG, "Data received was :" + data);


    }
}

public void sendTouchEvent(float xSet, float ySet)
{

}

@Override
public void run()
{

}

private void updateAssets()
{

}
}
```

When the code tries to receive a packet it just crashs on the socjet.receive( packet );
can anyone see any reason why?

Canvas

Comment: If `socket = new DatagramSocket( 50000 );` fails, socket.receive( packet ); will fail as socket will be null. Always make sure you cache all the possible exceptions such as `NullPointerException`, or wrap all the socket logic in one try/catch clause.

Comment: I will try that soon, but don't i need to tell the client what IP address it should try and look on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you have two `try` blocks. If the first one catches something socket stays `null`. So do something like that:

```
 DatagramSocket socket = null;
    try 
    {
        socket = new DatagramSocket( 50000 );
        byte[] buf = new byte[256];
        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket( buf, buf.length );
        socket.receive( packet );
    } 
    catch (SocketException e1) 
    {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Error with receiving data");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Make sure to `close()` the socket onDestroy of your Activity!**

Also consider AutoDiscovery instead of static IP's: [AutoDiscovery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796135/ip-autodiscovery)

Comment: what does AutoDiscovery do? what you send a simple packet and then receive the ip? I'm still abit confused on why the client doesn't need to know the IP address of the host? My host is on 192.168.1.59 which is the device's IP address on the LAN, how does my client know to receive a packet from that IP address?

Comment: in this case it sends something to all connected peers in your network. Now every of those knows the senders IP and can respond with "Hey, I am here take my IP". So you receive the IP of a client which is in your network but you don't know his IP.

Comment: But let's say I know what the hosts IP address is, could i get a client to start a datagram packet, send it to the host, the host would receive "connect", then the host will take the IPaddress of the "connect" message, send something to say you have connected, and then the host will store the IP address to keep sending out packets yea?

Comment: Let me explain it like that: your app is **A** and the device you want to connect with (but you don't know it's IP) is **B**. A and B are in the same network. Now A broadcasts any message to all peers. B (and other irrelevant peers) receive it and with the standart Android API you can also lookup the IP of A. Then B can directly send his IP to A. Now you you know B's IP. All you need to know at the beginning is the Port both clients are running on.

Comment: how would you broadcast A to B? if A doesn't know B's ip address? or do i atleast need to provide that?

Comment: It's ok, I changed my code so the server will wait to receive a packet, when a client is started, it will send a packet to the host, the host will receive it, it then takes the InetAddress from the packet and then uses it to send packets back, I just need to implement threads, so each client that connects is a new thread and is stored in an arrayList. Cheers for the help Bluewhile